# .NET Core console app doesn't recognize input args on linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, terminal

I have a simple .NET Core console app that prints the input parameters count:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WritLine($"You passed {args.Length} parameters");
    }  
  }
}
```

On Windows it works as expected.

I've build it as self contained app using a command:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

When I execute it on Ubuntu, no matter what I type after the program name it always returns `You passed 0 parameters` as there was no input.

Answer (score 0):

For me, finally, what worked was simply:
`dotnet myapp.dll myparam`

This works both in Windows and Docker(Debian buster).
.NET Core 3.1.